# How to create a 2-dimensional matrix of char using vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector

```
         #include <cmath>
         #include <cstdio>
         #include <vector>
         #include <iostream>
         #include <algorithm>
         using namespace std;
        int main() {

               vector<vector<char> > v(100, std::vector<char>(100));
               v[0]="apple";
               cout<<v[0];
               sort(v[0].begin(),v[0].end());
               cout<<v[0];
                  }
```

it should display apple before sorting and aelpp after sorting. But it's not compiling....any suggestion??
also suppose....v[0]="ebacd" ......v[1]="fghij"....and i want to apply v[0]-v[1]....such that resultant vector is of int type.....do i need to overload - operator

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/e.js/tnw0F2)

Comment: How did you get `v[0]="apple";` to compile ?

Comment: "its not working??" is this your question? The answer is: Not it is not working, the compiler starts complaining way before it reaches the line with the sort.

Comment: If you are interested, I made a convenient wrapper for a matrix-style object which allows expansion and contraction - [code available here](https://github.com/SJR276/crescent_library/blob/master/crescent_library/dynamic_matrix.h).

Answer (score 1):

vector and const char* are different types, and you can't use "=" operator. You want to copy char string to vector. Replace the string

```
v[0]="apple";
```

with

```
const char* apple = "apple";
std::copy(apple, apple + std::strlen(apple), std::back_inserter(v[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

v[0] is a vector, not a string
you can not use as a string, for example, the second line (assignment of a c-string).

Write it correctly, it does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a 2D array of char you can simply use a vector of string. It represents basically a 2D array as string is inherently array of characters.
Just declare `vector<string> v(100);`
That's it. It can be used as a 2D char array and you can access `v[i][j]`.

As for your code, you cannot initialize a `vector` of `char` with a `const char*`.
Just replace the `vector<vector<char> > v(100, vector<char>(100))` with the above string declaration and it works.

[Code](http://ideone.com/8DgyQU)

Comment: also suppose....v[0]="ebacd" ......v[1]="fghij"....and i want to apply v[0]-v[1]....such that resultant vector is of int type.....do i need to overload - operator

Comment: I guess yes, since you cannot do arithmetic operations on `strings` to return `int`. But I would suggest using a separate function, as it could mess up other string uses like concat using `+`, and just write `<return_type> your_operator(std::string s1, std::string s2);`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For what you are trying to do, you do not need a 2D vector.

Infact a 1d vector like  `vector<char> v;` is sufficent enough to sort characters.

All you need to do is store the characters of the word apple into the vector character by character..

```
v.push_back('a');
v.push_back('p');
v.push_back('p');
v.push_back('l');
v.push_back('e');
```

do the sorting..

```
sort(v.begin() , v.end());
```

and then display..

```
for (i=0; i<v.size(); i++)    cout<< v[i];
```

Full code listing:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {

int i;
vector<char> v;

    v.push_back('a');
    v.push_back('p');
    v.push_back('p');
    v.push_back('l');
    v.push_back('e');

    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Before sort\n";


    for (i=0; i<v.size(); i++)    cout<< v[i];

    sort(v.begin() , v.end());

    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"After sort\n";


    for (i=0; i<v.size(); i++)    cout<< v[i];

    cout<<"\n\n";

return 0;
}
```